# Xamarin WatchOS error when sending app to App Store "The WatchKitSupport2 folder is missing"

Tags: xamarin, watchos

I am using Visual Studio and Xamarin Forms to create watchOS app. When I send already built app, using Organizer in XCode I got  information:

> "ITMS-90484: Invalid WatchKit Support - The WatchKitSupport2 folder is
> missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of
> Xcode and resubmit it. "

My ipa file contains Payload folder and WatchKitSupport2 with WK file inside. I have and rebuild solution. What should I do to fix it?

I am aware of this https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/9618

Comment: This bug has been reported on Github. You could leave a comment to ask for the progesss. Have you try to use different versions of the XCode?

Comment: I have got installed XCode 12.5.1 yesterday. Right now I have installed newest XCode 13.1 and this bug still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio for Windows is broken in version 16.10.4 and 16.11.7 - it is not creating folder "WatchKitSupport2" (next to "Products" folder in  with "WK" file inside). Finally I have found a workaround to solve this issue by copy whole project from Windows to Mac, open it in Visual Studio for Mac, build (it creates "WatchKitSupport2" folder) and use Transporter to send it to Apple.